# Linker command failed with exit code 1 - not sure why

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm not sure exactly why i'm getting this. It usually comes because of a missing framework, except its mentioning a class I already have in my project, and imported into the file it's saying the error is on. It says...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ELCImagePickerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JCreateViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

JCreateViewController.m had this in the imports:

```
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
```

So i don't really know why it's giving me this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `ELCImagePickerController` in your project's Compile Sources build phase?

Comment: No, problem. That happens to everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the interest of providing an acceptable answer, from the comments:

Make sure `ELCImagePickerController` is included in your project's Compile Sources build phase.

Comment: How to add it ?

Comment: How to add this in Compile Source ??

Comment: Solved Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add resources to your projects build phases by simple select and add see this [link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/hi-i-faced-this-problem-and-want-to.html)