# Accidently Deleted View Controller. Program will not compile

Tags: ios, xcode, class, uiviewcontroller

I accidentally deleted my main view controller. I took it out of the trash and placed it back into xcode but now am still get 3 different errors

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_menuViewController in menuViewController.o


 "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_menuViewController in menuViewController.o

 error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It may be worth noting that menuViewController is the follow up VC from the main VC

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the file is targeted properly. Select the file in the left side of Xcode. Then view the file inspector (View, Utilities, Show File Inspector). Make sure the proper checkboxes are checked under Target Membership.

Comment: When I click on file inspector nothing appears to happen within Xcode

Comment: The file inspector pane will appear on the right side of Xcode. You may already have it showing.

Comment: I have done that for the .m and it has gotten rid of the errors. It will not allow me to click it for the .h file and the program crashes everytime it is run now?

Comment: A runtime crash is an entirely different issue and question. You can't setup target membership for .h files. So this question is now complete since you can build again. If you can't solve the crash, post a new question and be sure to include the relevant crash/error details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the file which you have added back again from the left side of the xcode and you will see the file Inspector on the right side. You make sure you select the Target Membership for your particular controller file. Keep in mind you can only select the Target Membership for the `.m` not for the `.h` file

[image]

In my case the target is **AttributeString**, so if you check the corresponding target to your file,clean and build the project and run, it will solve your issue.

Comment: I have done this now. Everytime I try to run the program it crashes before it loads

Comment: In the app delegate `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));` 
According to my break points it crashes at MAIN

Comment: you should see on the console , what you get on the console? this is the main.m class , you will be taken to this line of code everytime when you get some crash.

Comment: There are a series of them. 1)Expected member name or ';'after declaration specifiers
2)property requires fields to be named
3)expected ';' at end of declaration

Comment: you are missing `;`in your code, I can not tell you where you are missing, you should find out otherwise post your code.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the linker couldn't resolve references to your compiled VC. Check that you added the file to the correct target when you brought it back into Xcode. You can see this in the File Inspector (command-option-1).

When I'm seeing linker errors (or any other kind of weird, Xcode-what-are-you-doing behavior, I apply "Clean" (command-shift-K) or "Clean Build Folder" (option-command-shift-K) freely.

Using a version control system (Git or Subversion) would save you from this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I your ViewController included in your project's Compile Sources build phase?

You can see a link to a blog explaining this issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487025/2195998